# Dynamic Clickonce generation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, manifest

I have an application with multiple customers. I want to deploy the application using Click-Once.

There are two parameters that will be different between customers: The connection string in the `app.config` and the installation folder, so every time I should change these manually.

Is there a way to load these dynamically, for example from an XML file?

Comment: usually you don't get to decide where the app gets installed with clickonce. what do you mean exactly with the changing Installation Folder?

Comment: In VS,project properties, publish tab, there is "Installation folder URL"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio front-end for ClickOnce is not really flexible enough to deal with variations between different deployments of the same application. To achieve this kind of customisation, you will need to write your own deployment scripts using the command-line tools (e.g. [Mage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You could write a batch script or command-line application to:

1. Copy common application files into a temporary directory.
2. Add a customer-specific app.config file.
3. Generate the application and deployment manifest files using Mage.exe
4. Upload the contents of the temporary directory to a web server (or other location).

Instead of using the Publish wizard in Visual Studio, you can run your custom deployment script; either as a [post-build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) or as an [external tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx).